# Hyperlink (with query string) open new window specific size

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have GridView2 that populates from a query string. This is done by clicking a hyperlink in GridView1. It all works perfectly, **but I want the window to be a specific size instead of in a new tab.** How can I achieve this?

Here's my code in GridView1:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateHL">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HyperLink ID="hl1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("DateFormat", "~/DateProfile.aspx?sdate={0}") %>'><%# Eval("DateFormat")%></asp:HyperLink>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a call to window.open in the onclientclick event of the hyperlink instead of using navigateURL? You should probably try naming the window too.

[window.open method quick reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use `javascript:window.open()` in `NavigateUrl` or  event of

e.g:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("javascript:window.open('~/DateProfile.aspx?sdate={0}', 'MsgWindow','width=200,height=100')", Eval("DateFormat")) %>'
```

OR

You can try the following to `OnClick`:

```
OnClick='<%# Eval("DateFormat", "javascript:window.open('~/DateProfile.aspx?sdate={0}', 'MsgWindow','width=200,height=100')") %>'
```